# NPM 'should' library causes circular reference error when calling JSON.stringify on object

Tags: json, node.js, stringify

Now I know why I avoid libraries like should that modify the object prototype

It looks like I get this error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

when I `require('should')`

Is this expected?

before calling JSON.stringify, I can delete the properties from the object to be stringified like so:

```
  delete obj.should;
  delete obj.getShould;
```

but this is hard to do with nested objects etc. I have to say, this is pretty lame that should causes this, but maybe I am doing something wrong. How to fix this problem? I am writing a library and the user might `require('should')` so I have to protect against this type of issue.

Comment: turns out, the TypeError above comes from calling JSON.stringify on on error object that results from an assertion error thrown by the should library

Answer (score 2):

Though with slightly different output, util.inspect() provides output without circular reference breaking it. Also it provides means to customize the object inspection. Will it work for you?

Comment: Yes thanks it works for now, although eventually I will need to serialize objects with JSON

Answer (score 1):

`Should` is not setting properies directly on the object, but rather on it's [propotype](https://github.com/tj/should.js/blob/master/should.js#L1184-L1190):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'should', {
  set: function(){},
  get: function(){
    return should(this);
  },
  configurable: true
});
```

It must be something else that prevents an object from being serialized.

Comment: yeah, the error is actually a result of calling JSON.stringify on an assertion error object provided by should lib